# Why won't Adoptable Storage work on my H811 LG G4?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, adoptable-storage

I have an H811 LG G4 running the latest patches (20o) and can't get my adoptable storage to work for a 64G external SD card I plugged in. I've found a lot of info about bunk SD cards as well as many claims that LG has disabled adoptable storage/external SD because they didn't want a bunch of whining about performance hits. However, just as much info out there from people with this same device who *do* have access to their external SD card. One reddit thread I ran across showed how to use the `sm` command to enable adoptable storage. I can't seem to get this working however. The SD card I'm using is a Samsung EVO Class 10 and I am able to mount it and format it under Linux just fine. I have also tried using a different SD card known to be working in a camera with a VFAT filesystem on it. Again, works fine in Linux, fine in the camera, but LG G4 doesn't see it. I've checked dmesg output and have attached it grepping for mmc. It seems like the device is seeing two SD cards and one is throwing a `error -110` which google says is a timeout. Any thoughts?

This is the output of `sm` command:

```
   root@p1:/sdcard/tmo_update # sm has-adoptable
    true
    root@p1:/sdcard/tmo_update # sm list-disks adoptable
    root@p1:/sdcard/tmo_update # sm list-disks
    root@p1:/sdcard/tmo_update # sm get-primary-storage-uuid
    null
    root@p1:/sdcard/tmo_update # sm list-volumes all
    private mounted null
    emulated mounted null
```

Here is dmesg output:

```
[    8.747255 / 01-01 00:00:08.739][1] mmc1: mmc_sd_init_card() failure (err = -110)
[    8.747269 / 01-01 00:00:08.739][1] mmc1: error -110 whilst initialising SD card: rescan: 0
root@p1:/ # dmesg | grep mmc                                                   
[    0.834728 / 01-01 00:00:00.829][4] [200] read_image_info_from_emmc: total_image_num (36)
[    0.834832 / 01-01 00:00:00.829][4] [270] read_image_info_from_emmc: total_image_num (36)
[    2.287669 / 01-01 00:00:02.279][0] mmc0: no vqmmc regulator found
[    2.287697 / 01-01 00:00:02.279][0] mmc0: no vmmc regulator found
[    2.287894 / 01-01 00:00:02.279][0] mmc0: SDHCI controller on f9824900.sdhci [f9824900.sdhci] using 32-bit ADMA
[    2.327221 / 01-01 00:00:02.319][0] [LGE][MMC][mmc_rescan        ( ) START!] mmc0
[    2.344356 / 01-01 00:00:02.339][2] mmc1: no vqmmc regulator found
[    2.344385 / 01-01 00:00:02.339][2] mmc1: no vmmc regulator found
[    2.344583 / 01-01 00:00:02.339][2] mmc1: SDHCI controller on f98a4900.sdhci [f98a4900.sdhci] using 32-bit ADMA
[    2.402164 / 01-01 00:00:02.399][2] mmc2: no vqmmc regulator found
[    2.402194 / 01-01 00:00:02.399][2] mmc2: no vmmc regulator found
[    2.402379 / 01-01 00:00:02.399][2] mmc2: SDHCI controller on f9864900.sdhci [f9864900.sdhci] using 32-bit ADMA
[    2.402466 / 01-01 00:00:02.399][2] mmc2: mmc_add_host: device_disable_async_suspend
[    2.447215 / 01-01 00:00:02.439][2] mmc2: sdhci_msm_probe: device_disable_async_suspend
[    2.448061 / 01-01 00:00:02.439][1] mmc0: BKOPS_EN bit = 1
[    2.457339 / 01-01 00:00:02.449][0] [FS] mmc0: sdhci_msm_execute_tuning: finally setting the tuning phase to 10
[    2.464365 / 01-01 00:00:02.459][0] mmc0: new HS400 MMC card at address 0001
[    2.464383 / 01-01 00:00:02.459][0] [LGE][MMC][mmc_add_card      ( )] mmc_hostname:mmc0, type:MMC
[    2.464823 / 01-01 00:00:02.459][0] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 032G74 29.1 GiB 
[    2.464951 / 01-01 00:00:02.459][0] mmcblk0rpmb: mmc0:0001 032G74 partition 3 4.00 MiB
[    2.466834 / 01-01 00:00:02.459][0]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 p10 p11 p12 p13 p14 p15 p16 p17 p18 p19 p20 p21 p22 p23 p24 p25 p26 p27 p28 p29 p30 p31 p32 p33 p34 p35 p36 p37 p38 p39 p40 p41 p42 p43 p44 p45 p46 p47 p48 p49 p50 p51 p52 p53 p54 p55 p56
[    2.469498 / 01-01 00:00:02.459][0] [LGE][MMC][mmc_add_card      ( )] device_add & uevent posting complete!
[    2.514681 / 01-01 00:00:02.509][0] mmc2: slot status change detected (0 -> 1), GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH
[    2.585606 / 01-01 00:00:02.579][0] [LGE][MMC][mmc_rescan        ( ) START!] mmc1
[    4.677755 / 01-01 00:00:04.669][0] mmc2: slot status change detected (1 -> 0), GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH
[    4.677847 / 01-01 00:00:04.669][0] mmc2: slot status change detected (0 -> 1), GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH
[    6.837751 / 01-01 00:00:06.829][0] mmc2: slot status change detected (1 -> 0), GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH
[    6.837844 / 01-01 00:00:06.829][0] mmc2: slot status change detected (0 -> 1), GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH
[    8.747255 / 01-01 00:00:08.739][1] mmc1: mmc_sd_init_card() failure (err = -110)
[    8.747269 / 01-01 00:00:08.739][1] mmc1: error -110 whilst initialising SD card: rescan: 0
[    8.751137 / 01-01 00:00:08.739][1] [LGE][MMC][mmc_power_off     ( )] host->index:1, already power-off, skip below
[    8.751186 / 01-01 00:00:08.739][1] [LGE][MMC][mmc_rescan        ( ) START!] mmc2
[    8.751200 / 01-01 00:00:08.739][1] mmc2: mmc_suspend_host: enter 
[    8.755155 / 01-01 00:00:08.749][1] mmc2: mmc_suspend_host: exit 
[    8.755196 / 01-01 00:00:08.749][1] mmc2: mmc_resume_host: enter 
[    8.755207 / 01-01 00:00:08.749][1] mmc2: mmc_resume_host: exit 
[    8.829019 / 01-01 00:00:08.819][0] [FS] mmc2: sdhci_msm_execute_tuning: finally setting the tuning phase to 12
[    8.833221 / 01-01 00:00:08.829][0] mmc2: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x91 (3 bytes)
[    8.833264 / 01-01 00:00:08.829][0] mmc2: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDIO card at address 0001
[    8.833275 / 01-01 00:00:08.829][0] [LGE][MMC][mmc_add_card      ( )] mmc_hostname:mmc2, type:SDIO
[    8.833402 / 01-01 00:00:08.829][0] [LGE][MMC][mmc_add_card      ( )] device_add & uevent posting complete!
[    8.833413 / 01-01 00:00:08.829][0] mmc2: mmc_add_card: device_disable_async_suspend
[    8.849799 / 01-01 00:00:08.839][4] bcmsdh_sdmmc: bcmsdh_sdmmc_probe Enter
[    8.849904 / 01-01 00:00:08.839][4] bcmsdh_sdmmc: bcmsdh_sdmmc_probe Enter
[    8.858041 / 01-01 00:00:08.849][0] mmc2: slot status change detected (1 -> 0), GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH
[    8.858087 / 01-01 00:00:08.849][2] [LGE][MMC][mmc_rescan        ( ) START!] mmc2
[   10.315581 / 01-11 10:49:53.939][0] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p53): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: barrier=1
[   10.315609 / 01-11 10:49:53.939][0] SELinux: initialized (dev mmcblk0p53, type ext4), uses xattr
[   10.316240 / 01-11 10:49:53.939][1] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p54): Ignoring removed nomblk_io_submit option
[   10.318442 / 01-11 10:49:53.939][1] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p54): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: nomblk_io_submit,errors=remount-ro
[   10.318465 / 01-11 10:49:53.939][1] SELinux: initialized (dev mmcblk0p54, type ext4), uses xattr
[   10.365923 / 01-11 10:49:53.989][1] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p54): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: barrier=1,noauto_da_alloc,errors=continue
[   10.365950 / 01-11 10:49:53.989][1] SELinux: initialized (dev mmcblk0p54, type ext4), uses xattr
[   10.366938 / 01-11 10:49:53.989][1] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p55): Ignoring removed nomblk_io_submit option
[   10.371687 / 01-11 10:49:53.999][1] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p55): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 377080
[   10.372180 / 01-11 10:49:53.999][1] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p55): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 376938
[   10.374243 / 01-11 10:49:53.999][1] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p55): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 401977
[   10.375890 / 01-11 10:49:53.999][1] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p55): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 450610
[   10.376942 / 01-11 10:49:53.999][1] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p55): 4 orphan inodes deleted
[   10.383800 / 01-11 10:49:54.009][1] SELinux: initialized (dev mmcblk0p55, type ext4), uses xattr
[   10.419853 / 01-11 10:49:54.039][1] SELinux: initialized (dev mmcblk0p55, type ext4), uses xattr
[   10.440908 / 01-11 10:49:54.059][4] SELinux: initialized (dev mmcblk0p23, type ext4), uses xattr
[   10.447660 / 01-11 10:49:54.069][4] SELinux: initialized (dev mmcblk0p1, type vfat), uses mountpoint labeling
[   10.465462 / 01-11 10:49:54.089][4] SELinux: initialized (dev mmcblk0p41, type ext4), uses xattr
[   10.483082 / 01-11 10:49:54.109][4] SELinux: initialized (dev mmcblk0p40, type ext4), uses xattr
[   10.501178 / 01-11 10:49:54.119][4] SELinux: initialized (dev mmcblk0p42, type ext4), uses xattr
[   11.127447 / 01-11 10:49:54.749][4] init: Warning!  Service set_emmc_size needs a SELinux domain defined; please fix!
[   11.127468 / 01-11 10:49:54.749][4] init: Starting service 'set_emmc_size'...
[   11.176983 / 01-11 10:49:54.799][0] init: Service 'set_emmc_size' (pid 431) exited with status 0
[   22.549934 / 07-22 09:33:52.066][5] type=1400 audit(1469180032.066:6): avc:  denied  { relabelfrom } for  pid=463 comm="installd" name="busybox" dev="mmcblk0p55" ino=402123 scontext=u:r:installd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
[   22.550166 / 07-22 09:33:52.066][5] type=1400 audit(1469180032.066:7): avc:  denied  { relabelfrom } for  pid=463 comm="installd" name="sqlite3" dev="mmcblk0p55" ino=402127 scontext=u:r:installd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
[   28.469043 / 07-22 04:33:57.986][5] mmc2: slot status change detected (0 -> 1), GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH
[   28.469083 / 07-22 04:33:57.986][4] [LGE][MMC][mmc_rescan        ( ) START!] mmc2
[   28.700959 / 07-22 04:33:58.216][0] [FS] mmc2: sdhci_msm_execute_tuning: finally setting the tuning phase to 12
```

**UPDATE:** force adoptable

```
root@p1:/ # sm set-force-adoptable true                                        
root@p1:/ # sm list-disks                                                      
root@p1:/ # date
Fri Jul 22 16:51:49 CDT 2016
```

and the dmesg output:

```
[32495.404963 / 07-22 16:51:33.591][0] pet_watchdog
[32499.935271 / 07-22 16:51:38.121][1] type=1400 audit(1469224298.121:166): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=398 comm="vold" name="fd" dev="proc" ino=582796 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
[32499.936358 / 07-22 16:51:38.121][1] type=1400 audit(1469224298.121:167): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=398 comm="vold" path="/proc/389/cwd" dev="proc" ino=582798 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
[32499.936414 / 07-22 16:51:38.121][1] type=1400 audit(1469224298.121:168): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=398 comm="vold" path="/proc/389/root" dev="proc" ino=582799 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
[32499.936466 / 07-22 16:51:38.121][1] type=1400 audit(1469224298.121:169): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=398 comm="vold" path="/proc/389/exe" dev="proc" ino=582800 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
[32501.674275 / 07-22 16:51:39.851][5] type=1400 audit(1469224299.851:170): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=398 comm="vold" name="fd" dev="proc" ino=582796 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
[32501.675872 / 07-22 16:51:39.861][5] type=1400 audit(1469224299.861:171): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=398 comm="vold" path="/proc/389/cwd" dev="proc" ino=582798 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
[32501.675957 / 07-22 16:51:39.861][5] type=1400 audit(1469224299.861:172): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=398 comm="vold" path="/proc/389/root" dev="proc" ino=582799 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
[32501.676031 / 07-22 16:51:39.861][5] type=1400 audit(1469224299.861:173): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=398 comm="vold" path="/proc/389/exe" dev="proc" ino=582800 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
[32502.005651 / 07-22 16:51:40.191][0] [CC] current batt_temp[27], batt_temp_state[0], current batt_volt[4403], batt_volt_state[1]
[32503.399588 / 07-22 16:51:41.581][5] type=1400 audit(1469224301.581:174): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=398 comm="vold" name="fd" dev="proc" ino=582796 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
[32503.400788 / 07-22 16:51:41.581][5] type=1400 audit(1469224301.581:175): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=398 comm="vold" path="/proc/389/cwd" dev="proc" ino=582798 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
[32504.129651 / 07-22 16:51:42.311][3] SELinux: initialized (dev fuse, type fuse), uses genfs_contexts
[32504.137571 / 07-22 16:51:42.321][3] SELinux: initialized (dev fuse, type fuse), uses genfs_contexts
[32504.148736 / 07-22 16:51:42.331][3] SELinux: initialized (dev fuse, type fuse), uses genfs_contexts
[32504.161187 / 07-22 16:51:42.341][2] FUSE: SHORTCIRCUIT enabled [sdcard : 31316]!
[32504.161469 / 07-22 16:51:42.341][3] FUSE: SHORTCIRCUIT enabled [sdcard : 31315]!
[32504.162207 / 07-22 16:51:42.341][0] FUSE: SHORTCIRCUIT enabled [sdcard : 31314]!
[32505.428839 / 07-22 16:51:43.611][0] pet_watchdog
[32515.444837 / 07-22 16:51:53.631][0] pet_watchdog
[32516.244678 / 07-22 16:51:54.431][0] now = 4298188928, schedule = 4298201000, rounded schedule = 4298201100 => 4298201000
```

Comment: Could you try `sm set-force-adoptable true`, then `sm list-disks`?

Comment: Thanks. Nothing seems to have changed. I've updated the original question with the command.